# Macroeconomics questions

Tags: macroeconomics

Hello and Happy new year.

Is anyone can help me with macroeconomics questions?

(Dynastic Savings and Human Capital). Consider an economy in which parents invest in their children’s
human capital. At time t, generation t has bt bequests left by now-dead parents, a level of human capital
ht, and is hit by an idiosyncratic shock t. Human capital earns a constant rate of w, and generation t
invests in the next generation’s human capital while also leaving bequests bt+1, which earns a constant
interest of r. At time t + 1, the next generation begins working with the human capital level decided by
the previous generation, and so forth. Generation 0 solves
max E0 "X10 βtu(ct)# ;
subject to a budget constraint
ct + bt+1 + xt+1 = wht + (1 + r)bt;
ht+1 = xα t+1hγ t t; α + γ ≤ 1
bt+1 ≥ 0; xt+1 ≥ 0
where xt+1 is the investment into the next generation’s human capital. There is no population growth,
so we can normalize population size to 1. But each dynasty is hit by i.i.d. shocks  (so dynasties are
heterogeneous) to human capital investments. Also assume that  shocks have a mean of 1.
Note that next generation’s human capital depends both on investments, and also the current generation’s
human capital. But the shock t is known at time t.

1. Formulate the Bellman equation for this problem. What are the state variables and how many are
   there? What are the controls? Is it possible to reduce the number of states?
2. Derive the Euler equations for optimal bequests and human capital investment.
3. Suppose that α + γ < 1. Compare the returns to human capital and bequests. What are the returns
   to human capital investments? Can it ever be the case that a parent doesn’t invest in their children
   (xt+1 = 0)? Can the returns to human capital investments ever be larger than 1 + r?
4. Continue to assume that α + γ < 1. Suppose there is no shock, i.e.  = 1 for all individuals and for
   all eternity. Further suppose that bequests are traded among individuals at time t, i.e., if I want to
   save for my offspring, someone must be borrowing for themselves, so r is determined in the market.
   Can there be a BGP equilibrium in which β(1 + r) > 1?
5. Continue to assume that α+γ < 1. Show that the only possible BGP is a steady state with no growth.
   Derive an upper-bound for the steady state interest rate, denoting the steady state distribution of (b; h) as F(b;h)